# Kitten in a parvo infected litter not showing any signs. Could she be negative for infection?

Tags: cats, diseases

I had recently rescued a cat with her 7 week old litter. Got the mom vaccinated and neutered and she has found a forever home and I have taken in the litter of three kittens. This was  two weeks ago. I had immediately taken them for their first checkup and hade wormed them the next day.

Over the next couple of days the boy vomited and I one of the girl had loose stools. I dismissed it as a side effect of the deworming medicine and made sure they were drinking water and we're eating wet food.

The symptoms continued for the next three days and the boy's vomiting had become more frequent with a decreasing appetite which prompted me to have him checked.

To my horror , the doctor suspected Parvo and got the tests done and it turned out to be exactly that. I immediately got him admitted to the the vet hospital near by and they started his care immediately.

The following day the girl also started crashing , fortunately I was able to spot distemper signs in her much earlier and I had her admitted as well.

The third one is still with me. She is the first born and right from the start I had  noticed that she had the biggest appetite and was very active.

Surprisingly , it's been more than 7 days since all three of them were separated and the third kitten isn't showing any signs of distemper yet. She continues to have a voracious appetite ( feeding her 4 times a day and I have to put up with her incessant crying for food as well ) her stools seem normal as well.

What are the chances that she could have some how missed the bullet by luck ? I made sure that separated her litter and feeding / water bowls and cleaned them thoroughly

I'm skeptical since the three of them shared the same litter boxes and almost always wanted to eat from each other's bowls.

What should I do ?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! If in worry for the health of your pets, please do mot wait for the guesses of strangers from the internet. Only a vet could tell you, if your pet is at risk.